# the_category() tag not styling HTML or CSS

Tags: theme-development, template-tags, categories

I am having problems getting my the_category() template tag to style accordingly with the rest of my theme. I believe this is because the HTML isn't output the same way as the the_author() and the_comments() tags. I've looked into my category_template.php file but am having trouble identifying what exactly I need to tweak to get it to style the same.

Here is my code for the category post details:

```
                    <a href="<?php get_category_link( $category_id ); ?>" class="post-item">
                        <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>
                        <?php the_category( '&bull;' ); ?>
                    </a>
```

I am almost certain there is a filter I need to apply in the category_template.php page but am not sure what to change. For a visual demonstration look at http://blog.diginomics.com

EDIT: I've used your advice with some success. It is falling in place and styling correctly, but now I have two category links. Take a look at the page. Here is my index.php code:

```
<?php the_category( '&bull;' ); ?>
```

And here is my category_template.php:

```
$categories = get_the_category( $post_id );
foreach ($categories as $category){
echo '<a class="post-item" href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . '<li class="fa fa-tags"></li>&nbsp;' . $category->cat_name . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) returns an array with all the categories

```
$categories = get_the_category();

foreach ($categories as $category){
echo '<a class="post-item" href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>';

}
```

Tha code should work, you can modify it to add the `title`

Also, calling `the_category` echoes the result, that why i'm using the this function

Comment: I've edited the original post to show updated code with your recommendation.